# Web application for managing a library of papers

Tags: publications, citations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping track of bibliography references for an entire research group](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/854/keeping-track-of-bibliography-references-for-an-entire-research-group)

Is there a web application which can help the researchers at my group collaboratively manage a collection of scientific papers?

Desired features are:

- easily upload pdfs and edit bibliographic info
- query the database
- export the database (or a subset) as a BibTeX file
- define subsets/folders of publications (e.g., all papers related to a project, all papers by members of the group etc.)
- should be accessible only for members
- should be hosted on our own servers

Comment: There are many… In fact, there's a whole [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) on that topic, which includes many of the criteria you are looking for. You can also check the table in [this nice blog post](http://mahbub.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/comparison-of-free-bibliographic-managers/), although it's a bit dated.

Comment: In particular, you can investigate: [Aigaion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aigaion/), [Bebop](http://www.alari.ch/people/derino/Software/Bebop/index.php), [refbase](http://www.refbase.net/index.php/Web_Reference_Database), and [phpBibliography](http://phpbibliography.sourceforge.net).

Comment: We have a set of PHP scripts which generate output akin to http://www.sat.ltu.se/publications/ . We don't export to bibtex, because bibtex is the input!

Comment: [Bebop](http://www.alari.ch/people/derino/Software/Bebop/index.php) looks nice.

Comment: Mendeley, citeulike. Check [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36/21) question out and the answers.

Comment: I'm not looking for a web service like Mendeley or citeulike. It should be self-hosted.