# How to create a collaborative list of references

Tags: online-resource, reference-managers

I am working in academia in a very wide field of research mixing a lot of different domains. This broadness is also a problem, since there is no proper references for the basis of the theory, and we have to deal with a lot of material scattered in very different places, often in the form of lecture notes, conference proceeding or unpublished documents.

Therefore, I would like to propose a collaborative online list of these references, in a light way so that anyone could add or improve the list. The best current list of references is [here](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/afrefs.html), which is neither up to date nor really easy to use (no tags, list by authors, etc). I would like something slightly more powerful, I though about some framework like Django but don't really know if it is a suitable solution.

I would like to be able for anyone to

- sort in different ways
- add tags
- add or edit references entries
- rate difficulty (this is a bonus)
- comment (this is a bonus)

Moreover, it should be better if the list were accessible without any amount on a simple webpage.

Any suggestion in order to do such a list is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/)? It provides both an online interface and a client. You can add notes and tags to resources, which can also be organized in folders. You can also create "groups" to share (part of) your library with others. There is a con: it is owned by Elsevier, which I'd rather not support. There are also [alternatives](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/free-open-source-substitutes-for-mendeley) but I haven't tried any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition. I also am not fond of Elsevier, and use instead Zotero for a similar system I suppose. However, I really would like something open on the web, available for everyone without needing to subscribe to a service or download a daemon. This is similar to a rough HTML list, but that can be updated by anyone and also a bit more convenient (with different options for sorting references, etc.)

Comment: I think Zotero would let somebody participate on this purely on the web, without the client. They would have to be signed up for a free Zotero account, though. I think the same applies with Mendeley. 

If you don't want people to have to join anything.... well, you could look at open collaborative editing systems - the simplest is probably Etherpad - but then *anybody* can edit, so you're open to vandalism.

Comment: @Flyto I didn't know Zotero has a web-based option made for group sharing, that seems perfectly relevant and exactly what I want! Thank you very much for this tip

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, so no promises - but definitely worth checking out.

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus as far as I know, you can install Zotero on your own webserver and use that if you want to keep everything in house

Answer (score 0):

If you want a broad and open list, then I suggest Google sheets and integrate it with Google Sites and Google Forms. that seems to fill your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however Google is blocked in China...

Comment: Microsoft Office actually has colaborative options [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-word-documents-with-real-time-co-authoring-7dd3040c-3f30-4fdd-bab0-8586492a1f1d] mmhh.. I don't know if Github is allowed in China. But it could be an option if it is.