# Is it possible to download paper from academia.edu without being registered there?

Tags: publications, social-media

Based answers to [Is Academia.edu useful?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44632/is-academia-edu-useful) it seems that there are some legitimate reason why many people would prefer not to have academia.edu account.

On the other hand, it might happen that you see a paper there which is interesting for you and which might be difficult to obtain in a different way.

I have noticed that when I find some paper on academia.edu using Google Scholar, I will also have a direct link to download. To give one random example, when searching for [ultrafilter site:academia.edu](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=ultrafilter+site:academia.edu) you can see that I get direct download link to [this paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/37277308/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56TQJRTWSMTNPEA&Expires=1469695028&Signature=nu7JRVImZUDnRMdO7Pc9vqQiI10%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DIntroduction_to_the_Keisler_Order.pdf). (The link contains the string "expires", so it is probably only temporary.)  On the other hand, when I try to find the same paper [on academia.edu](http://www.academia.edu/11902653/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order) and try to download it, I am asked to login/sign up.

Is there some way to get the url for download from academia.edu website without being logged in? (This could be useful if neither Google Scholar nor some other searches give me a direct download link to the article.)

**EDIT:** To clarify (since I received an answer copying parts of the above paper). When I made this post, I was able to download it via the direct download link I have mentioned above. And this particular paper is also available [on another website](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Gannon.pdf). So this is *not a request for a paper*. (Requesting papers would clearly be an incorrect use of academia.SE.) It is a question whether the annoying restriction to be registered before downloading something from academia.edu can be somehow bypassed. I have simply chosen a random paper as an illustration.

Answer (score 5):

Google Scholar provides the direct link `http://www.academia.edu/download/37277308/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order.pdf`. It seems like there are two identifying elements: the code `37277308` and the filename `Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order`. Both appear in the source of the [article page](https://www.academia.edu/11902653/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order) on academia.edu even when you are not logged in, for instance here:

```
  registrationParams: {
    doc_id: 37277308,
    splash: true,
    redirect: "https://www.academia.edu/11902653/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order?auto=download",
  }
```

So in theory it should be possible to recover the direct link by piecing them together. I don't know if there is software already available, but it does definitely seem possible to write, for instance, a Greasemonkey script that adds direct download links to these pages.

Of course, all of this depends on the specific format of academia.edu's webpages and direct download links, which are subject to change at any time. In particular, if they find out that many people are using them, I suppose they will quickly change the format to pull the plug and force people to login.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Maybe I am missing something, but the link from your post http://www.academia.edu/download/37277308/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order.pdf returns Page Not Found. (At least for me.)

Comment: @Martin Hmm - interesting. It seems that there is some sort of referrer check; clicking on the same link from scholar.google.com downloads it, but copying the link target and pasting it doesn't work.

Comment: I did not think of that. Using `wget --referer http://scholar.google.com "http://www.academia.edu/download/37277308/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order.pdf"` indeed worked.

Comment: @Martin Do you know whether your solution still works? I tried the one explained by the answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: @m0_as When I tried the wget command from my previous comment, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use inspect element (ctrl + shift + i). find (ctrl + f) the link with this word  >>amazonaws.com<< . you need to copy the link from 'http' to 'pdf'  >>http......................pdf<< , then paste it in new tab or download manager

Comment: Is there in fact a difference between inspect element and view source? However, I have tired Inspect element a few times on [this page](http://www.academia.edu/11902653/Introduction_to_the_Keisler_Order), but I did not find any occurrence of the string "amazonaws". (I did it in Google Chrome, if that matters.)

Comment: It does not have to be *amazonaws*, just search for "pdf".