# Can Mendeley create a folder based on a bibliography?

Tags: reference-managers

I have used Mendeley to manage references in a paper and create a bibliography. I would like to place all the cited references into one folder in Mendeley - is there a way of doing this automatically?

The reason is to be able to share the selected references in a group.

Comment: May find something useful here : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/854/72855