# How can I store sources in a structured manner?

Tags: books, reference-managers, note-taking

I started writing a book on my own in lockdown about some critical social issues. For this I read some books online to gain more knowledge about the issue I am writing about (all books are online), and I read some news articles as well, which are as important as the books. The problem I face is this: how do I store those article in a well-structured manner? For example, if I am reading some articles on some specific topic, how I store them so that when I required I find them again later?

Edit:) thanks for ur kind response to all,I felt that I need to somewhat elaborate more about my problem, actually I did download Mendeley after getting referred from this site, but the problem is it store the only citation not the complete page of the article (for e.g. [here](https://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/energy-and-environment/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-fall-in-water-reserves/article23785470.ece)) now I want to store this complete article for future reference and I want to store this kind of articles in a right folder.

Comment: Look for library solutions. Mendeley is a free option for example. Google for library or citation managers and you will see options.

Comment: The regular file search on windows 10 is quite good for pdfs. Can automatically read and search through the text contained in the pdf itself. Returns results quickly. You can add additional tags to the pdf just by adding to the file name, and then search for the tag later. Easier than mendeley

Comment: Zotero is quite similar to Mendeley but doesn't require an account and doesn't surveil and commercialize user behavior.

Comment: @marts  I edited the question now for better understanding.

Comment: Citavi can store PDFs, for example. I am afraid you have to go through several reference management tools to evaluate their capabilities.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/854/keeping-track-of-bibliography-references-for-an-entire-research-group

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is one (or more) of the following:

- [Reference management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) allows you to store, organize and retrieve bibliographic information about literature. Almost all of them interface with word processors to output citations and reference lists, and online sources, such as journal websites and the DOI system, to easily obtain bibliographic information. Most of them also allow you to include your own notes with any entry.
- [Qualitative data analysis (QDA) software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_qualitative_data_analysis_software) allows you to highlight, store, and organize relevant sections and quotes from all kinds of digital texts (including ebooks and articles). These text snippets can then be analyzed to discover relations between them; very useful to organize literature around various topics, e.g. for a literature review/survey article.
- [Note-taking software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_note-taking_software) allows you to ... take notes. Some are very minimalist, and some are infinitely extensible. With [org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode), for example, you could probably compile your own hybrid form of note-taking, QDA, and reference management from scratch.

Comment: I edited the question now please have a look!

Comment: @Jack Rod almost all reference managers can store copies of pdfs or websites. Your problem is probably that you don't have access to the article.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a really important question in terms of using sources that are perishable. I would recommend first making sure that sources are archived using the wayback machine, that way the current versions are accessible to you and everyone in the future.

I solve this problem using Zotero! Zotero works a lot like Mendely, but it's browser plug in is really nice and can save PDFs and the HTML website linked to the citation. I also use betterBibTeX and Zotfile as extensions to improve the workflow and let me not only save the pages themselves but also my notes on them.

Comment: Mendeley has browser plugins, too.

Comment: @marts Yes! I was a mendely user previously, but the zotero plug in has been better at saving things in my experience.

Comment: Also, if downvoters could let me know how to improve this answer I'd appreciate it! This answer directly addresses the question in a way that is standard in academia.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your answer sounds like an advertisement. That might be it.